# Как перекрыть блок с тенью схожим блоком?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

в данный момент делаю аккордеон, в нем у каждого из заголовков есть тень, но если блоки находятся рядом тени между ними быть не должно (а у меня они наезжают друг на друга).
Задаю я тень каждому из заголовков одинаково для того что бы если между блоками будет контент у меня сверху и снизу у блока или блоков была тень.
Выглядит оно примерно вот так:
[image: Как то так]

Оно так то почти правильно вот только тень которая наезжает друг на друга все портит.
Главное не убрать тень которая идет по контуру блоков, а только внутреннюю

```
.container{
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.checkout-body{
  &__section{
    &-title{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
      overflow: hidden;

      .section-title__number{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: 10px;
        background-color: green;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;

      }
    }
    &-body{
      display: none;
    }

  }
}
```

Вот сам код:
http://jsfiddle.net/d7WGb/556/